# Pattern Match parameters in a changeset

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to have two changeset clauses in one of my schemas that are matched based on the number of parameters passed in.

The first changeset would match only when the name and vendor_id were present (and no other fields).

`Product.changeset(struct, %{ name: name, vendor_id: vendor_id })`

The second changeset will match everything else:

`Product.changeset(struct, params)`

Unfortunately when `name` and `vendor_id` and other parameters are passed the first changeset is invoked.

I'm not sure how to construct the changesets so that they do what I would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map_size/1` in a guard for this. Not a very elegant solution (you need to hardcode the size in the guard), but since pattern matching maps ignores extra fields, I can't think of a better way.

```
def changeset(struct, %{name: name, vendor_id: vendor_id} = params) when map_size(params) == 2 do
  ...
end
def changeset(struct, params) do
  ...
end
```